# Oracle Java Stored Function - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

Attempting to call a java stored function and get a java object back and convert it to an oracle type.
This is a 10g database and we are using Java 1.4.2. ( I know upgrade is the answer, unfortunately I am constrained to this environment.)

Code and errors listed below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TestMapping.java

```
public class TestMapping {
    public static TestObject getResponse(){
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
        testObject.setMyTestValue("TEST");

        return testObject;
    }
}
```

TestObject.java

```
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class TestObject implements SQLData {
    private String myTestValue;

    private String sqlTypeName;
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sqlTypeName;
    }

    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        sqlTypeName = typeName;
        myTestValue = stream.readString();
    }

    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(myTestValue);
    }

    public String getMyTestValue() {
        return myTestValue;
    }

    public void setMyTestValue(String myTestValue) {
        this.myTestValue = myTestValue;
    }
}
```

Command Line:

```
javac TestObject.java
javac TestMapping.java
loadjava -user user/pass@server:1521:instance -t -r TestObject.class
loadjava -user user/pass@server:1521:instance -t -r TestMapping.class
```

Oracle Type:

```
create or replace
type test_object  as object(
myTestValue  varchar2(50));
```

Publish Java Function:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION test_mapping RETURN test_object
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'TestMapping.getResponse() return TestObject';
```

Anonymous Block to Test:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
  response test_object; 
begin
  response := test_mapping();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('myTestValue : ' || response.myTestValue);
end;
```

Error:

```
Error report:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a return value that is an instance of a user defined Java class convertible to an Oracle type got an object that could not be converted
ORA-06512: at "USER.TEST_MAPPING", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 4
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to return a java object into oracle. What are you going to do with that object? You'd be better either returning the properties of the object or if you just want to store the object use a blob and persist the object to a blob field in a database table

Comment: I am trying to make a call to real time CC auth. 10G Wallet according to Oracle doesn't support SHA2. So I have made a java stored function to make the call to a web service over SSL and I wanted to return an object that matches up to a Oracle type. I basically worked around it and returned a JSON string to the PL/SQL and parsed with PLJSON.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an instance of `oracle.sql.STRUCT`, not an instance of your custom Java type.  This is true both in your Oracle publication...

```
create or replace
FUNCTION test_mapping RETURN test_object
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'TestMapping.getResponse() return oracle.sql.STRUCT';
```

... and in the Java class ...

```
public static oracle.sql.STRUCT getResponse(){ ...
```

To build the STRUCT that `getResponse()` must return, you need to do something like this:

```
// This is the object you really want to pass back
TestObject result;

STRUCT oracleResult;
try{
  StructDescriptor resultStructDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TEST_OBJECT", yourOracleConnection);

  Object[] attributes = {result.myTestValue};
  oracleResult = new STRUCT(resultStructDescriptor, yourOracleConnection, attributes);
} catch ( SQLException e ) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
return oracleResult;
```

Comment: How do I get "yourOracleConnection" though? I'm technically already in the database, since im running the jvm in the database?

Comment: Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");

Comment: I found it already, but I feel like this is information is kinda important in this context. Thanks dude!